Deduce Mean Value inequality from Mean Value Theorem for real-valued functions: generic norm
It is a known result that if $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, and we have $a,b\in U$ such that the segment $[a,b]\subset U$, then there exist an intermediate vector $c\in [a,b]$ such that
$$df(c)(b-a) = f(b)-f(a)$$
It is easily derived from the Mean Value Theorem for real functions, just defining an auxiliar function $g(t)=a+(b-a)t$, and considering the composition.
I know that the result does not hold for the case of vector-valued functions (just consider $f(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. But it is known that an inequality can be derived. To be precise,
$$
\lVert f(b)-f(a) \rVert \leq M \lVert b-a \rVert
$$
with $M = \sup_{c\in [a,b]} \lVert df(c) \rVert$.
I have seen a nice proof taking a unit vector and using an auxiliary function $g(t)=\langle u, t \rangle$, but I think this only holds for the Euclidean norm. Is this right? Could I prove it for any norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

You need to be careful with the norms: the norm used on $df(c)$ should be the dual norm to the norm used on $b-a$. For the Euclidean case both coincide. The unit vector $u$ needs to have dual norm equal one, i.e., $| u|* := \sup{ |t |\le 1} t^Tu=1$.

Yes, I didn't say it, but the norm of $\lVert df(c) \rVert$ is the operator norm. But could I extend the proof for any norm in $\mathbb{R}$. I think no, because the proof uses Cauchy-Schwarz, and not every norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ comes from an inner product.

check dual norms, there also a generalized CS-inequality holds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm#Finite-dimensional_spaces

So... what is your suggestion then? I take $u$ unitary in the desired norm, and I can consider its dual $u^$, and define $\phi(t)=u^ t$?

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be differentiable. Let $X:=\mathbb R^n$, $Y:\mathbb R^m$ with norms $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$.
Let $\|\cdot\|_*$ denote the dual norm of $\|\cdot\|_Y$:
$$
\|u\|_* := \sup_{ y: \ \|y\|_Y\le 1} y^Tu.
$$
Then we have $ u^Ty \le \|u\|_*\|y\|_Y$ and $\|y\|_Y = \sup_{ u:\ \|u\|_* \le 1} y^Tu$.
Take $a,b\in X$, $u$ such that $\|u\|_* \le 1$. Define
$$
g(t) := u^T f(a + t(b-a)).
$$
Then $g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, and there is $s\in (0,1)$ such that
$$
g(1) - g(0) = u^T (f(b)-f(a)) = g'(s)  = u^T f'(a + s(b-a)) (b-a).
$$
Then
$$
u^T (f(b)-f(a)) \le \|u\|_* \| f'(a + s(b-a)) (b-a)\|_Y
\le \|u\|_* \sup_{s\in(0,1)}\|f'(a+s(b-a))\|_{op} \| b-a\|_X,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is the operator norm of a linear map from $ X$ to $Y$, i.e. $\|f'(x)\|_{op}:= \sup_{h: \ \|h\|_X\le1} \|f'(x)h\|_Y$.
If we take in the above inequality the supremum with respect to $\|u\|_* \le 1$, then we get the desired inequality:
$$
\|f(b)-f(a)\|_Y = \sup_{u: \ \|u\|_* \le 1} u^T (f(b)-f(a)) 
\le \dots \le \sup_{s\in(0,1)}\|f'(a+s(b-a))\|_{op} \| b-a\|_X.
$$

Questions to make sure I understood: $f'(c)(b-a)$ means $df(c)(b-a)$, that is, the differential of $f$ at point $c$ acting on the element $b-a$, right? Also, in the dual norm I could take $\sup_{\lVert y \rVert =1}$ instead of $\lVert y \rVert \leq 1$,right? Because of the properties of the operator norm (I know the different ways of computing operator norms in general).

And $\lVert u \rVert$ would be the supremum of $|u^T y |$ with $y$ unitary in its corresponding norm?

yes to the question on $f'$. the sup can be replaced by $ |\cdot|=1$, I like the $\le$ more as it works also for the trivial vector space ${0}$. For the sup it does not matter whether we include absolute values or not.

Your proof is very clear, specially for someone who is already familiar with the operator norm. I am surprised in some books there appears the proof for the Euclidean norm but not this.

one more question if you don't mind. Can you prove that given $y$, It IS possible to choose $u$ such that $u^T y=\lVert y \rVert$ without using Hanh-Banach? Knowing that we are working with $\mathbb{R}^n$ seems to me that the answer is yes, but I don't know how to prove it.

These unit balls are compact, then vectors realizing the sup exist.
